# Firebase Database Structure - Users, Groups and Lists

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

I am planning a mobile application to use Firebase as its database/authentication provider mainly because I have found the authentication really easy to implement and also because of the apps nature. The app itself revolves around users in groups. Within each group is a range of data that will be accessible by every user in that group.

I am wanting some feedback on my proposed firebase database structure and if there is anything I should do differently or could do better.

Current proposed structure:

```
{
    "users": {
        "userID": {
            "userName": ...
            "email": ...
            "group": groupID
            "creationTime": ...
        }
    },

    "groups": {
        "groupID": {
            "name": ...
            "members": {
                "userID": true
                "userID": true
            }
        }
    },

    "lists": {
        "groupID": {
            "name": ...
            "items": {
                "itemID": true
                "itemID": true
            }
        }
    },

    "items": {
        "itemID": {
            "name": ...
            "createdBy": userID
            "timeCreated": ...
        }
    }
}
```

Here are a few things I want to clarify:

**Is it wise to seperate lists and groups or should I embed the items within each list object?**

**Am I okay using groupID as the identifier for both the groups and lists seeing as there will only be one list linked to each group?** This was means I can easily access this list from the users "group" variable.

Comment: @Mistalis I havent tried anything at this stage as I am still planning. I want to sort out the structure before implementing the code for it.

Comment: did you ever get this addressed, and can I ask, if you wanted to get the users in a particular Group and display the Lists items where you able to do so with ta query?

Answer (score 1):

The Firebase Database documentation recommends keeping your data flat, not nesting unrelated types of data. It seems you're trying to do that, so that sounds good.

If you flatten your data, you will need to have a way to relate items in the various lists with each other. The simplest way to do that is by giving the corresponding items the same key in all lists. They're like PK/FK in a relational database, except that Firebase (unlike most relational DBMSs) doesn't manage the relation for you.

The topic of data modeling is incredibly broad and it's hard to do it justice in a Q&A format. I highly recommend reading [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/) and viewing our [Firebase for SQL developers](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s) series. You'll also find a lot of data modeling questions in [this list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firebase-database+nosql).

Comment: Thanks for your response. In the case of my lists and the items linked within them, these items will not be shared between multiple lists. Each item is unique to that list, so would it make sense to just embed those items within the list?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I can't post a comment. I would recommend to make your life easier to have the same ID each of the data. Also, look into userIDs and PushID, they might come handy.

To get push id you can:

```
 DatabaseReference mypostref = databaseRef.push();
 mypostref.setValue(data);
 String mypostref.getKey());
```

and you get userID:

```
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
user.getuID
```

Have something like this:

```
    {
        "users": {
            "userID": {
               PushID: {
                "userName": ...
                "email": ...
                "group": groupID
                "creationTime": ...
                 userID: ....
                 pushID ....
            }
          }
        }
        },

        "groups": {
            "userID": {
               PushID: {
                "name": ...
                "members": {
                    "userID": true
                    "userID": true
                     userID: ....
                     pushID ....
                }
            }
          }
        },

        "lists": {
            "userID": {
               PushID: {
                "name": ...
                "items": {
                    "itemID": true
                    "itemID": true
                     userID: ....
                     pushID ....
                }
            }
        }
      },

        "items": {
            "userID": {
               PushID: {
                "name": ...
                "createdBy": userID
                "timeCreated": ...
                 pushID ....
            }
        }
    }
  }
```

Think of userID as your primary key and pushID and unique identifier. There can be one user (uID) who can have many data under them (pushID)

Comment: Yeah that was my idea with "groupID" being used for both the listID and the groupID. In this instance I would use the push ID for creating the group as its groupID and then create a list with this same ID.

Comment: To get specific data back you need to store the uID and pID as values for each data set.

Comment: Think of userID as your primary key and pushID and unique identifier. There can be one user (uID) who can have many data under them (pushID)

Comment: I dont quite understand what you are trying to do with the database example you just showed. What is the point in having userID with pushID inside? And why would you need userID within group? Each group is going to be used by multiple users.

Comment: By having user id and push id stored in as values it will make it easier for you to query data back to Android. I believe you have used getters/setters? if so, for example you can say IF getPushID MATCHES the PUSHID in database print only THAT data.

Comment: If you don't store user id and push id as values you won't be able to get specific values back and instead only be able to read data as a whole.