# NoSQL query of items,lists, Groups and Users using Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

Am looking at the data structure in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41932304/firebase-database-structure-users-groups-and-lists) and want to know how you would go about getting the emails of users who belong to a certain group when they could belong to several groups and the GroupID stored against that user is the current group they are participating in?

Do you store the email addresses with the userid under the "members" or, instead, for each member of the group, get that user's email address from the "users" document userid (this would mean iterating through the group/members collection and doing a query for each user. Not very efficient).

Am used to SQL so this is all new to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a single node for each user

```
/users/UID/emails/
/users/UID/emailunread/
/users/UID/settings/
/users/UID/details/
/users/UID/payments/
```

So you can simply do a **subscription** for a singular node path `this.myDatasubscription = this.DB.list('users/' + this.uid).snapshotChanges()` ensuring changes like new emails or account settings will detected and rolled out in real time back to the app, so your are using angular/ng or something similar client side then your variables `{{this.email_list}}` should update real time with no page changes.

Take a look at this one.
[error: Property 'getChildren' does not exist on type 'DataSnapshot'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51667824/error-property-getchildren-does-not-exist-on-type-datasnapshot/51668117#51668117)

Comment: I should also mention that NoSQL you might have to save the data twice, such as payment information the aim to to reduce queries